# Полнотекстовый поиск ничего не выводит

Tags: php, sql, полнотекстовый-поиск

При обработке запроса на поиск в базе ничего не выводит в таблицу, вероятно ошибка в сиснтаксисе но не вижу где при добавлении var_dump после запроса выдает

> string(110) "SELECT * FROM `sandoz` WHERE MATCH (AssetType,
>   AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, SN, CR_IMEI) AGAINST ('01')"

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', 'Admin', 'testdb');
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
 {
   echo "Извините возникла проблема на сайте";
   echo "Ошибка: Не удалось создать соединение с базой MySQL и вот почему: \n";
   echo "Номер ошибки:".$mysqli->connect_errno."\n";
   echo "Ошибка:".$mysqli->connect_error."\n";
   exit;
 }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `novartis` WHERE MATCH (AssetType, AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, SN, CR_IMEI) AGAINST ('". $_POST["search"] ."')";
 if (!$run = $mysqli->query($sql))
 {
   echo "Извините, возникла проблема в работе сайта";
   echo "Ошибка: Наш запрос не удался и вот почему: \n";
   echo "Запрос:".$sql."\n";
   echo "Номер_ошибки".$mysqli->errno."\n";
   echo "Ошибка:".$mysqli->error."\n";
   exit;
 }
 $result = array();
 if ($run && mysqli_num_rows($run) !=0)
 {
   while ($rs = $run->fetch_assoc())
    {
     $result[] = $rs;
    }
 }

 foreach($result as $key=>$val)
 {
     if ($val['Asset_Status']=='01_Active') {
         $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#e6f9ff;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='02_Reserved') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#b3ffb3;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='03_Available') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#e6fff2;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='04_Repair') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#ccccff;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='05_Repair_InStock') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#9999ff;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='06_Discarded') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#e6fff2;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='07_Sold') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#ffffe6;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='08_Lost') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#ffb3b3;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='09_Stolen') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#ffcccc;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='10_Destroyed') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#cc0000;">';
     }
     elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='11_Repair_User') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#6666ff;">';
     }
       elseif ($val['Asset_Status']=='12_History') {
           $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#ffe6ff;">';
     }
     else {
         $data .= '<tr>';
     }
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Inventory_LLC'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Inventory_DD'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetCategory'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetType'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetSubtype'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Transfer_Date'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Return_Date'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['UniqID'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Owner'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Comp'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Location'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Status'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Status'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Entry'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['SN'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Notes'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['CR_IMEI'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Org_Unit'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Position'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Cost'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Any_Val'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Pur_Date'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Check_Uncheck'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Local_Material'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['PO'].'</td>';
   $data .= '<td>'.$val['Activated'].'</td>';
   $data .= '</tr>';
 }
 ?>

 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: middle;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */
input[type=text]:focus {
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="sandoz.php">Sandoz</a>
      <a href="alcon.php">Alcon</a>
      <a href="pharma.php">Pharma</a>
      <a href="#">Vodafone</a>
      <a href="#">Employees</a>
      <a href="test.php">TEST</a>
    </div>

    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</span>

    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
 </script>

 <form method="post" action="handler.php">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Inventory_LLC</th>
      <th>Inventory_DD</th>
      <th>AssetCategory</th>
      <th>AssetType</th>
      <th>AssetSubtype</th>
      <th>Transfer_Date</th>
      <th>Return_Date</th>
      <th>UniqID</th>
      <th>Asset_Owner</th>
      <th>Owner_Comp</th>
      <th>Owner_Location</th>
      <th>Owner_Status</th>
      <th>Asset_Status</th>
      <th>Asset_Entry</th>
      <th>Serial_Number</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>CR_IMEI</th>
      <th>Org_Unit</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Any_Val</th>
      <th>Pur_Date</th>
      <th>Check_Uncheck</th>
      <th>Local_Material</th>
      <th>PO</th>
      <th>Activated</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?=$data?>
    </tr>

    </table>
<script>
  function Inv_LLC_search() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
  }
</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Ошибки выбивает какие-то ?

Comment: Проверьте у вас точно на всех полях по которым вы хотите произвести поиск, стоит полнотекстовый индекс ?

Comment: @madfan41k ошибок никаких, да во всех полях

Comment: @madfan41k перезагрузил apache и mysql все заработало, хз че было

Comment: @madfan41k еще такой вопрос можно ли в такой запрос добавить LIKE %search%?

Comment: немного оффтопа, но `$styles = ['01_Active' => "#e6f9ff;", ....]`, и `$data .= "<tr style=\"background-color: {$styles[$val[Asset_Status]]}\">"`

Comment: @teran пока что пишу как знаю, спасибо за сокращение

Comment: @Elanyl а зачем там LIKE ? он же и так по всему тексту ищет

Comment: @madfan41k например чтобы весь серийник не вводить в поиск или если это возможно как реализовать с помощью FULLTEXT